# How to Add Api Permissions to an Azure App Registration using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am figure out the commands in Azure PowerShell to add an the `User.Read` Ape Permission to my App Registration in Azure.

[image: An existing application]

I can find some examples using `*Azure`, but would prefer one that uses the `*Az` commands, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-2.8.0.

Wonder if anybody knows how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I _think_ you need [Get-AzADAppCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azadappcredential?view=azps-3.8.0) and [Get-AzADApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azadapplication?view=azps-3.8.0), changing the verb to **New** if you need to amend them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can currently only be achieved using the **Azure AD PowerShell**. Please note that there is a difference between [Azure AD PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/overview?view=azureadps-2.0) and [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-2.8.0). The [Azure AD PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/overview?view=azureadps-2.0) is not simply the [old Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.13.0) module. 
Azure AD PowerShell is a separate module. There is no "AZ*" for Azure AD yet. Only couple of [most commonly used commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/?view=azps-3.8.0#active_directory), that have Azure Resource Provider implementation. 
Azure PowerShell has a limited set of features for working with Azure AD. If you need more features, like the one you mention, you must use Azure AD PowerShell. Azure AD PowerShell is *not* depricated and is the officially supported PowerShell module for working with Azure AD.

You can manage these required permissions by the [Set-AzureAdApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) cmdlet and passing proper `-RequiredResourceAccess` object.

In order to construct this object, you must first get a reference to "exposed" permissions. Because permissions are exposed by other service principals.

as I cannot upload whole file, here is a PowerShell script that creates a sample application with required permission to some MS Graph and some Power BI permissions.

```
Function GetToken
{
    param(
        [String] $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/dayzure.com/oauth2/token",
        [String] $clientId,
        [String] $clientSecret,
        [String] $resourceId = "https://graph.windows.net"
    )
    $scope = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($resourceId) 
    $encSecret = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($clientSecret) 
    $body = "grant_type=client_credentials&resource=$($scope)&client_id=$($clientId)&client_secret=$($encSecret)"
    $res = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $authority -Body $body -Method Post
    $authResult = $res.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    return $authResult.access_token
}

#`
#            -RequiredResourceAccess @($requiredResourceAccess)
#

Function CreateChildApp
{
    param (
        [string] $displayName,
        [string] $tenantName
        )
    # create your new application
    Write-Output -InputObject ('Creating App Registration {0}' -f $displayName)
    if (!(Get-AzureADApplication -SearchString $displayName)) {
        $app = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $displayName `
            -Homepage "https://localhost" `
            -ReplyUrls "https://localhost" `
            -IdentifierUris ('https://{0}/{1}' -f $tenantName, $displayName) 

        # create SPN for App Registration
        Write-Output -InputObject ('Creating SPN for App Registration {0}' -f $displayName)

        # create a password (spn key)
        $appPwd = New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId $app.ObjectId
        $appPwd

        # create a service principal for your application
        # you need this to be able to grant your application the required permission
        $spForApp = New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId $app.AppId -PasswordCredentials @($appPwd)
    }
    else {
        Write-Output -InputObject ('App Registration {0} already exists' -f $displayName)
        $app = Get-AzureADApplication -SearchString $displayName
    }
    #endregion

    return $app
}

Function GrantAllThePermissionsWeWant
{
    param
    (
        [string] $targetServicePrincipalName,
        $appPermissionsRequired,
        $childApp,
        $spForApp
    )

    $targetSp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($targetServicePrincipalName)'"

    # Iterate Permissions array
    Write-Output -InputObject ('Retrieve Role Assignments objects')
    $RoleAssignments = @()
    Foreach ($AppPermission in $appPermissionsRequired) {
        $RoleAssignment = $targetSp.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq $AppPermission}
        $RoleAssignments += $RoleAssignment
    }

    $ResourceAccessObjects = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess]'
    foreach ($RoleAssignment in $RoleAssignments) {
        $resourceAccess = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess"
        $resourceAccess.Id = $RoleAssignment.Id
        $resourceAccess.Type = 'Role'
        $ResourceAccessObjects.Add($resourceAccess)
    }
    $requiredResourceAccess = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
    $requiredResourceAccess.ResourceAppId = $targetSp.AppId
    $requiredResourceAccess.ResourceAccess = $ResourceAccessObjects

    # set the required resource access
    Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $childApp.ObjectId -RequiredResourceAccess $requiredResourceAccess
    Start-Sleep -s 1

    # grant the required resource access
    foreach ($RoleAssignment in $RoleAssignments) {
        Write-Output -InputObject ('Granting admin consent for App Role: {0}' -f $($RoleAssignment.Value))
        New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $spForApp.ObjectId -Id $RoleAssignment.Id -PrincipalId $spForApp.ObjectId -ResourceId $targetSp.ObjectId
        Start-Sleep -s 1
    }
}

cls

#globaladminapp
$clientID = "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee"
$key = "****"


$tenantId = "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-xxxx-yyyy-aaaaaaaaaaaa";
$TenantName = "customdomain.com";
$AppRegName = "globaladminChild-0003";

$token = GetToken -clientId $clientID -clientSecret $key

Disconnect-AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $token -AccountId $clientID -TenantId $tenantId

$appPermissionsRequired = @('Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy', 'Device.ReadWrite.All', 'Domain.ReadWrite.All')
$targetServicePrincipalName = 'Windows Azure Active Directory'

#$appPermissionsRequired = @('Files.ReadWrite.All','Sites.FullControl.All','Notes.ReadWrite.All')
#$targetServicePrincipalName = 'Microsoft Graph'

$app = CreateChildApp -displayName $AppRegName -tenantName $TenantName
$spForApp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($AppRegName)'"


$appPermissionsRequired = @('Tenant.ReadWrite.All')
$targetServicePrincipalName = 'Power BI Service'
GrantAllThePermissionsWeWant -targetServicePrincipalName $targetServicePrincipalName -appPermissionsRequired $appPermissionsRequired -childApp $app -spForApp $spForApp

$appPermissionsRequired = @('Files.ReadWrite.All','Sites.FullControl.All','Notes.ReadWrite.All')
$targetServicePrincipalName = 'Microsoft Graph'
GrantAllThePermissionsWeWant -targetServicePrincipalName $targetServicePrincipalName -appPermissionsRequired $appPermissionsRequired -childApp $app -spForApp $spForApp
```

The interesting parts are around "apppermissionrequired" and "targetserviceprincipalname" variables.

Comment: As sad as it is, this is the current state.

I'm just adding this comment to make sure others are aware that a consequence of not being part of the Az module, is that the authentication you typically use with Az (Connect-AzAccount) does not work with AzureAD.

If you have a script that needs to use both Az modules and AzureAD, you need to login using each module's respective commands.

Even worse, AzureAD brings ADAL with it, and it's not possible to load ADAL and MSAL in the same PowerShell session (dll conflict).

Comment: As a complement of this answer, also check https://rajanieshkaushikk.com/2019/07/31/how-to-assign-permissions-to-azure-ad-app-by-using-powershell/

Answer (score 1):

I can't reply to Rolfo's comment directly as I don't have enough clout yet.  While it's true it's not dead simple, it's possible to use both in the same session as of July 2021.  Not sure this was always the case, or something was updated to allow it.

```
#Import modules if needed
$mList = @("AzureAD","Az.Resources","Az.Accounts")
foreach($m in $mList){if ((gmo -l $m).Count -eq 0){Install-Module -Name $m -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Force}}

#Authentication Popup
Connect-AzAccount

#Use authentication context cached from above to authenticate to AAD graph
$IDObject = Get-AzAccessToken -Resource "https://graph.windows.net"
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $IDObject.token -AccountId $IDObject.UserId
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

With the new Graph API we can use the following command to add API permissions to an App Registration/Service Principal using PowerShell. It's much simpler than the old process.

```
Add-AzADAppPermission -ApplicationId "$spId" -ApiId "00000009-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" -PermissionId "7504609f-c495-4c64-8542-686125a5a36f"
```

(This is the case for the PowerBI API)

If deploying via an Azure Devops Pipeline I often recommend using the following script to authenticate into AAD:

```
  echo "Install Azure AD module..."
  Install-Module -Name "AzureAD" -Force
  Import-Module AzureAD -Force

  echo "Connect Azure AD..."
  $context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
  echo $context
  $graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
  echo $graphToken
  $aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken
  Write-Output "Hi I'm $($context.Account.Id)"
  Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id -MsAccessToken $graphToken
  echo "Connection ends"
```

Comment: Can you add an API permission using [Microsoft Graph PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/overview?view=graph-powershell-1.0) ?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the script to update Roles in App registration using Az module Powerhsell Script

````
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$roles,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$TargetAppId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$SourceAppId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$tenantId,
)
Connect-AzAccount


$rolestoArray=@($roles)
$rolesArray = $rolestoArray -split ','
$appRegistration =Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $TargetAppId
foreach($roleName in $rolesArray){
    $resourceObjectId=(Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $SourceAppId).Id
    $appRoles = (Get-AzADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $resourceObjectId).AppRole
    $roleId =  ($appRoles | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq $roleName} ).Id
    Write-Host The roleid is $roleId
    $App=Get-AzADServicePrincipal -Filter  "AppId eq '$TargetAppId'"
    if($App)
    {
        Add-AzADAppPermission -ApplicationId $TargetAppId -ApiId $sourceAppId -PermissionId $roleId -Type Role 
    }
}```
````