# Add a permission to AAD application via PowerShell script

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to create an azure active directory (AAD) application. Here is the command I use:

```
$uiApp = New-AzADApplication    -DisplayName $uiAppDisplayName `
                                -AvailableToOtherTenants $false `
                                -ReplyUrls $replyUrls `
                                -RequiredResourceAccess $requiredResourceAccess
```

How do I update the script to add a permission and select one of my APIs?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have created app using following command:

```
$DisplayName = "kavrepoApp"
$redirecturi = "https://jwt.ms"
$newapp=  New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $DisplayName  -ReplyUrls $redirecturi
$newapp
```

To get the service principal of app:

```
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | Where-Object {$_.AppId -eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'}
$sp.Oauth2Permissions | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq 'e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d'}
$sp


$app = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId '6a881bdd-4410-4918-baf6-546a77b8080a'
$svp = New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId $app.AppId
$appsvp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | Where-Object {$_.AppId -eq $app.AppId }
$appsvp
```

#api to which the API permissions need to be granted.

```
$apiAppId="ffbxxxx7" 
$apIObj="10xxxxx"
$api=Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $apIObj
$api
```

To grant permission , you must be the owner , so to make an owner follow commands:

```
az ad app owner add --id
                    --owner-object-id
```

Used following commands to add API permission and grant admin consent:[See az ad app permission | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cli/azure/ad/app/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-permission-list-grants)

**`az ad app permission add --id "<yourAppId>" --api <Api-AppId  --api-permissions <scope-resourceId>=Scope`**

or

**`Add-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId 9cc74d5e-1162-4b90-8696-65f3d6a3f7d0 -ApiId 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 -PermissionId 5f8c59db-677d-491f-a6b8-5f174b11ec1d`**

see [add-azadapppermission | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/add-azadapppermission?view=azps-9.6.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-9.4.0)
or

```
az ad app permission add --id "1xxxb" --api "xxx"  --api-permissions e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d=Role
```

[image]

**`az ad app permission grant --id "<yourAppId>" --api <Api-AppId>--scope <scope-resourceId>`**

[image]

Also see [How to Add Api Permissions to an Azure App Registration using PowerShell - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61457429/how-to-add-api-permissions-to-an-azure-app-registration-using-powershell)